# notifyDataSetChanged and keyboard

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Why keyboard hiding when I call pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ??
I'm using https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager .
This library using ViewPager. And when i call notifyDataSetChanged and software keyboard is visible, keyboard hiding.

```
public class WizardAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private int cutOffPage = -1;
        private BaseFragment primaryItem;

        public WizardAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return pages.get(i).createFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            if (object instanceof WizardFragment) {
                Page page = ((WizardFragment) object).getData();
                if (!pages.contains(page)) {
                    return POSITION_NONE;
                }
            }

            if (object == primaryItem) {
                // Re-use the current fragment (its position never changes)
                return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
            }

            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

            primaryItem = (BaseFragment) object;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            int count = 0;

            if (cutOffPage >= 0) {
                count = Math.min(cutOffPage + 1, pages.size());
            } else if (pages != null) {
                count = pages.size();
            }

            return count;
        }

        public int getCutOffPage() {
            return cutOffPage;
        }

        public void setCutOffPage(int cutOffPage) {
            this.cutOffPage = cutOffPage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain your problem properly?

Comment: @Badrul In my case, call notifyDataSetChanged is important. And i don't want hide keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, this should work

```
//Import this
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

//Create object
private InputMethodManager imm;

imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: This is bad , I just hide keyboard and after, show. I need perfectly result. How disable keyboard hiding when call notifyDataSetChanges ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick **and dirty** fix might be to force the keyboard to appear by calling:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Or

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I'm try, but it's reality dirty )

Comment: @smail2133 Please try using `listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);` when creating the ListView and let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: I don't used listview. Using viewPager;