# Android calling notifyDatasetChanged() on a listview is hiding keyboard input

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-softkeyboard, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `RecyclerView` that is being filtered as I type on an `EditText` View. After I type, perform the filtering and publishing the results, I am calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` so I see the results on the screen. However the user might still need to type, but `notifyDatasetChanged()` is causing the keyboard to hide.

```
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        outputItems = (ArrayList<Item>) filterResults.values;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
```

I tried to force the keyboard back up after notifyDatasetChanged() but it did not work. Any suggestions?

I understand the solution could be that the user presses "done" or something else to perform the filtering. But I would like to have a realtime solution.

Comment: Tried `listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24651162/5192105 Try this and let me know.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi sorry I meant to write RecyclerView I am not using list view. And for your second comment this does not always work. when list size changes a lot, the keyboard still goes down.

Comment: @user7331538 Hi, I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RecyclerView you can use setHasStableIds after your adapter initialization

```
myAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)
```

Additionally you need override getItemId function inside your adapter implementation for generate a unique id for each element of your recyclerView like this:

```
class MyAdapter(private var items: MutableList<MyItem>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    ...

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return items[position].id
    }
}
```